# Discord.js v12 - Balance Command with MySQL

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently trying to create a money system for my discord bot.
The balance itself is working but the issue I have is that it does not add the user id / any balance to the database if the user id does not exist yet.

Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../config.json");
const mysqlconfig = require("../mysqlconfig.json");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const date = new Date();
const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth();
var mysql = require('mysql');
const { release } = require("os");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    var con = mysql.createPool({
        host: mysqlconfig.host,
        user: mysqlconfig.user,
        password: mysqlconfig.password,
        database: mysqlconfig.database,
        port: 3306
      });
            
            var sql = `SELECT * FROM money WHERE userID = '${message.author.id}'`
                con.query(sql, async function (err, results, userID, balance, fields, rows) {
                    let data = results.map(v => {
                        //console.log(v.userID)
                        if(message.author.id = v.userID) { // checks if message.author.id is equal to any id in the database
                        message.channel.send(`You have **${v.balance}** YeetCoins!`)
                        return v.balance
                        } else { // if not it should add the id and also add 100 coins
                        var sql1 = `INSERT INTO balance (userID, balance) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userID=VALUES(userID)`

                        con.query(sql1,[message.author.id, '100'], function (err, result, balance, userID) {
                            
                        });
                        message.channel.send(`added 100 coins to <@${message.author.id}>'s balance!`)
                        }
                        
                    })
                })
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "balance",
    category: "User"
}
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong sadly.
Hope anyone could help me with that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling a function when you try to insert the new member. You don't need that. All you want to do is insert something into the table. No need for a function.

```
con.query(sql1, [message.author.id, '100']);
```

*Note: When you first query the database you call a bunch of parameters that you don't need. The ones you need are `err` and `results`. Once the data is there you don't need to `map` it. You can just work with it.*

In addition to that your way of checking if the user exists in the first place is a little wonky. You try to call on something that might not exists because `SELECT * FROM money WHERE userID = '${message.author.id}'` should return **exactly one** row if the user exists and zero rows if he doesn't. So you should check if rows are present at all before you check if the id matches.

```
if (!results.length) {
    // here we insert the new user
}
```

If your query returned something you can then check if the userID matches. If it doesn't you have a problem with your database but it never hurts to check. *Note: We need to use `===` here because we want to check the exact value.*

```
if (message.author.id === results[0].userID) {
    // return the balance here
}
```

Once all is said and done your resulting query should look a little something like this.

```
con.query(sql, function (err, results) { // we don't need the other values
    if (err) throw err; // check if something went wrong

    if (!results.length) { // check if there are rows and insert if there aren't
        var sql1 = `INSERT INTO money (userID, balance) VALUES ('${message.author.id}', '100')`;
        con.query(sql1); // no need for a function here
        return message.channel.send(`added 100 coins to ${message.member}'s balance!`); // return here so the rest doesn't get executed
    }
    // check if the IDs match
    if (message.author.id === results[0].userID) {
        message.reply(`You have **${results[0].balance}** YeetCoins!`); // we reply to the user who calls this command.
        return results[0].money;
    }
})
```

Comment: Ohh this makes alot more sense! I'm really glad you explained what I did wrong in this way, that actually helps lots. Especially since I'm rather new to nodejs & mysql. Really appreciate it!

Comment: It seems like it's still not inserting the `balance` if the userID does not exist

Comment: but it inserts the userID?

Comment: Oh totally forgot what I really wanted to write. It does not insert anything

Comment: check if your initial query actually returns something. Does it give you any erros?

Comment: Found the issue :). `INSERT INTO balance` it should've been `INSERT INTO money` but now the `You have **${v.balance}** YeetCoins!` part aint working

Comment: oh, thats actually my bad. You need to use `rows[0]` everywhere you want to access the data because you are accessing something that is essentially an array.

Comment: That's what I tried too but it didn't change anything as far as I can tell

Comment: What exactly is not working? Just the message part or is it not even going into the if statement?

Comment: sorry, should've been more precise. It's not going into the if statement

Comment: make sure that your collumn is actually called `userID`. Also I should've said `results[0]` not `rows[0]`. Make sure that is correct as well.

Comment: It is called `userID` and yes I used `results[0]` but it does not even get to the if statement. Not exactly sure why it is the case tho

//EDIT: it does seem like it doesnt even return `results.userID` if I console log before the if statement

Comment: Do you have any error message? Because it works for me just fine

Comment: That is unfortunate because I can't reproduce that error. Add me on discord so we can chat there. Worthy Alpaca#2063